# Lucene.NET with Windows Azure

Tags: lucene.net, azure-blob-storage

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 site hosted on Windows Azure. I needed full text search in this site so I used Lucene.NET. Lucene is using a Windows Azure Blob to store the indexing files. Currently, a query takes a long time (approx. 1 min). When I look in Fiddler, I notice that 285 requests are fired off to the Blob storage.

My Blob storage currently only has 10 files in it. The largest file is only 177kb. I also noticed that the Dispose call takes ~20 seconds. Here is my code. I don't feel like I'm doing anything too crazy

```
IndexWriter indexWriter = InitializeSearchIndex();
if (indexWriter != null)
{
  foreach (var result in cachedResults)
  {
    var document = new Document();
    document.Add(new Field("Name", result.Name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    document.Add(new Field("ID", result.ID.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    document.Add(new Field("Description", result.Description, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    document.Add(new Field("LastActivity", result.LastActivity, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    indexWriter.AddDocument(document);
  }
  indexWriter.Dispose();
}
```

At the same time, I'm not sure why this is taking so long.

Comment: Leo has a great blog post on Lucene with Sql Azure here: http://leoncullens.nl/post/2012/11/18/Full-Text-Search-on-Azure-with-LuceneNET.aspx Maybe it can help you? I have a similar implementation and it is lightning fast over millions of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your search set is small/bounded you might want to have a look at the cache (preview) version of a Lucene.NET directory I wrote - it will be MUCH faster than a blob based directory:

https://github.com/ajorkowski/AzureDataCacheDirectory

Of course... if you expect to have an unbounded number of documents etc this wont be an optimal solution.

I know that Lucene.NET creates a bunch of temp files and then combines them at points... Perhaps calling `.Optimise` or something similar might combine all the temp files before it actually gets to the point of pushing them up to blob storage (I think this step is obsolete in the newer Lucene.NET versions though...)